# Prisma db push error failed to connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: prisma

When I use de command npx prisma db push, i got the following error

Error: request to https://binaries.prisma.sh/all_commits/22b822189f46ef0dc5c5b503368d1bee01213980/windows/migration-engine.exe.gz.sha256 failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.33.108.27:443

Does anyone have any ideia how to solve this? this only happens when i'm working under a proxy server

Comment: Which prisma version are you using?

Comment: prisma version 3.8.1